# How to use KBinsDiscretizer to make continuous data into bins in Sklearn?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I am working on a ML algorithm in which I tried to convert the continuous target values into small bins to understand the problem better. Hence to make better prediction. My original problem is for regression but I convert into classification by making small bins with labels.

I did as follow,

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import KBinsDiscretizer  
est = KBinsDiscretizer(n_bins=3, encode='ordinal', strategy='uniform')
s = est.fit(target) 
Xt = est.transform(s)
```

It shows a value error like below. Then I reshaped my data into 2D. yet I could not solve it.

> ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import KBinsDiscretizer

myData = pd.read_csv("train.csv", delimiter=",")
target = myData.iloc[:,-5]  # this is a continuous data which must be 
                        # converted into bins with a new column.

xx = target.values.reshape(21263,1)

est = KBinsDiscretizer(n_bins=3, encode='ordinal', strategy='uniform')
s = est.fit(xx) 
Xt = est.transform(s)
```

You can see my target has 21263 rows. I have to divide these into 10 equal bins and write it into a a new column in my dataframe. Thanks for the guidance.

P.S.: 
Max target value:185.0
Min target value:0.00021

Comment: It is tough to replicate your example without knowing what data is inside "train.csv". You don't have to give the exact data, but it would be helpful to provide sample data for `myData` or `target`. 

edit: I see that the target value range has been provided, but the above is still a good general guideline to follow when posting questions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Okay I was able to solve it. In any case I post the answer if anyone else need this in the future. I used `pandas.qcut`

```
target['Temp_class'] = pd.qcut(target['Temeratue'], 10, labels=False)
```

This has solved my problem.

Comment: You're a genius! Thanks a lot.

Comment: How do you get back the original column from the binned column. ?

Answer (score 7):

The mistake in your first attempt is you are giving the output of fit function into transform. `.fit()` returns the fitted model and not the input data. The correct way would be either of one of the below.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import KBinsDiscretizer  
est = KBinsDiscretizer(n_bins=3, encode='ordinal', strategy='uniform')
Xt = est.fit_transform(target)
```

or

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import KBinsDiscretizer  
est = KBinsDiscretizer(n_bins=3, encode='ordinal', strategy='uniform')
est.fit(target)
Xt = est.transform(target)
```

Answer (score 6):

I was having a similar problem while working with the Titanic dataset. I found that one of my functions had converted my column into a float, and by changing it to an integer, that seemed to help the problem. Also, calling the specific column name with double square brackets worked for me:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import KBinsDiscretizer
est = KBinsDiscretizer(n_bins=5, encode='onehot-dense', strategy='uniform')
new = est.fit_transform(dataset[['column_name']])
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is to realize that the `fit_transform` needs a `DataFrame` as an input and not a `Series`. The error means that a series is a 1D object while the `fit_transform` needs a 2D object i.e. a `DataFrame`. So, for example, you can do:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import KBinsDiscretizer  
est = KBinsDiscretizer(n_bins=3, encode='ordinal', strategy='uniform')
Xt = est.fit_transform(pd.DataFrame(target))
```